# Function that returns tribonnacci series up to a number

Tags: python, function, while-loop, logic, iteration

I am trying to solve an exercise that requires me to write a function that takes as input an integer which then returns a list of tribonacci terms up until the input value. I have been "successful" for the most part but an extra term is output as well. This is my code:

```
def tribonacci(m):
    tribs = [0, 0, 1]
    if m == 0 or m == 1:
        tribs = [0, 0]
    elif m == 2:
        tribs = [0, 0, 1]
    else:
        while tribs[-1] < m:
            tribs.append(tribs[-1] + tribs[-3] + tribs[-2])
    return tribs
```

I understand that the issue is the while loop which runs an extra iteration because the last element is still not greater than m. However, I can't see immediately how to fix this. I would resort to a while-else loop, but I'd like to see some other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compare the term that is about to be genrated with m, like this:

```
def tribonacci(m):
    tribs = [0, 0, 1]
    if m == 0 or m == 1:
        tribs = [0, 0]
    elif m == 2:
        tribs = [0, 0, 1]
    else:
        while tribs[-1] + tribs[-3] + tribs[-2] < m:
            tribs.append(tribs[-1] + tribs[-3] + tribs[-2])

    return tribs
```